# Routes return 404 in express-openapi

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, openapi

I'm pretty new with openapi, and I'm trying to convert an existing express app to work with openapi.

I've followed the documentation, and tried converting 1 of my routes to openapi (while canceling all others, to make sure I'm not mixing both methods).
In a preview, I see the documentation working fine, but when I start the server, I can't reach my routes. I get 404 when I call http://localhost:4001/getDevices.

The structure of my project:

`src/`

`src/api/getDevices/get.ts`

`src/openapi/openapi.yaml`

`src/openapi/components/schemas/Device.yaml`

`src/openapi/components/parameters/DeviceSearchQuery.yaml`

`src/openapi/paths/getDevices.yaml`

I initialize the openapi in my Server class, as follows:

```
class Server {
  public app: Application;
  public server: http.Server;

  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
    this.server = http.createServer(this.app);
  }

  async start(port: number): Promise<void> {

    // Define the options for the initialize function
    const options = {
      apiDoc: join(__dirname, '../openapi/openapi.yaml'),
      app: this.app,
      paths: path.join(__dirname, '../api/'),
    };

    // Call the initialize function with the options
    initialize(options);

    // Start the server
    this.server.listen(port);

  }
}
```

And start is called in my entry point.

openapi.yaml:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: AWS Proxy API
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:4001
    description: Local server

tags:
  - name: Devices
    description: Device management

paths:
  /getDevices:
    $ref: './paths/getDevices.yaml'

components:
  parameters:
    DeviceSearchQuery:
      $ref: './components/parameters/DeviceSearchQuery.yaml'
  schemas:
    Device:
      $ref: './components/schemas/Device.yaml'
```

getDevices.ts:

```
export async function getDevices(request: Request, response: Response): Promise<void> {
  // some logic
}
```

getDevices.yaml:

```
get:
  tags:
    - Devices
  operationId: getDevices
  parameters:
    - $ref: '../components/parameters/DeviceSearchQuery.yaml'
  responses:
    '200':
      description: Successful operation
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '../components/schemas/Device.yaml'
    '400':
      description: Invalid parameters
    '500':
      description: Server error
```

If I add a regular path /test and call that, not via openapi, it works as expected.

I kinda got lost at this point, I might have mixed some things up already, but I'm really not sure what I'm not doing wrong here.
I'd love some assistance to understand my error, and what I should be doing instead of what I already am.

Thank you! (and be gentle, I'm new)

Answer (score 0):

*Hi St.Nicholas and everyone else,*
above you wrote your API getDevices endpoint file is "src/api/getDevices/get.ts" but then a bit later you wrote the name is "getDevices.ts:". *That confuses me a little.*

To resolve the issue, make sure to follow the resource-based approach for your API files. Thats **because OpenAPI is REST conform** and **REST follows a resource-based approach**.
Avoid using "getDevices.ts" or "getDevices/get.ts" as the file name for your "device"-resource, because in express-openapi you can implement multiple endpoints for one resource ("devices") in a single file. Instead, create a file named "devices.ts" for the "device"-resource also if you just want to implement one http method endpoint.

Also, remember to export the express endpoints function following the express-openapi convention, using lowercased HTTP method names like "get," "post," etc., for each endpoint:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

export async function get(request: Request, response: Response): Promise<void> {
    // Logic to retrieve devices and send the response
}

export async function post(request: Request, response: Response): Promise<void> {
     // Logic to create a new device and send the response
}

export async function put(request: Request, response: Response): Promise<void> {
    // Logic to update a device and send the response
}

export async function del(request: Request, response: Response): Promise<void> {
    // Logic to delete a device and send the response
}
```

Here is the express-openapi docs about that and pay special attention to the "args.paths" property:
https://github.com/kogosoftwarellc/open-api/tree/main/packages/express-openapi#initializeargs

I think that brings you a good bit closer to your problem, now you just have to understand the "args.paths" property correctly based on the documentation and adjust the paths correctly.